# I integrated Firebase SDK into my app, but it keeps saying I haven't

Tags: ios, firebase, sdk

I integrated Firebase SDK into my iOS app. I then recreated the app (fixed a lot of things) and reintegrated it again. However, it's not working anymore. It keeps telling me to integrate the SDK even though I've already done it. Debug also works and I see events coming through.

Do I need to create a brand new account?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd like to help you, but I need more information. What do you mean when you say it keeps telling you to integrate the SDK? I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: Thanks Jen, actually I couldn't get it to work, so I just created a new account. Thanks so much for your help though. :)